# On BigQuery Modify or Delete a Job

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to update a query configured in a BigQuery job?
Currently from the documentation, I only see query being set everytime a new query job is created.

```
const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob({
    jobId: fetchJobId,
    query: `<SELECT-STATEMENT-HERE>`,
  });
```

If there's no way to programmatically update query configured in the job, is there a way for at least to delete the existing query job programmatically? So I can just create a new one, with the new query.

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant. Tried using "const [cancelResponse] = await bigquery.job(fetchJobId).cancel();"   but when i try to call "createQueryJob" it gives me the error "ApiError: Already Exists: Job <job-id>". So I guess cancel doesn't really delete the existing job? but just stops the current processing for the job?

Comment: According to the documentation you can cancel a job using an API as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#cancelling_a_job). Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: what is your use case? why you cannot just cancel (jobs.cancel) job (assuming something went wrong and you still have time enough to do so) and then create (jobs.insert) new job?